# Why most cursive forms of two Chinese characters, "不" and "正", have a different shape that violates the stroke order?

Tags: traditional-characters, calligraphy

Tell me why most cursive forms of Chinese character, "不", is shaped like this:

[image]
[image]

Instead of this?:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Looks like four dots.
And another Chinese character, "正", shaped like this:

[image]
[image]

Instead of this?:

[image]

Why is this exists,
Tell me how is this **exists**?!

Answer (score 10):

There might be a bit of misunderstanding about where cursive script comes from. Many cursive characters **do not** actually come from [regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script), but are derived from [Warring States era brush calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) and [seal script shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_script).

---

This here

[image]

cannot approximate the shape or follow the stroke order of

<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
23.1
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image: 㐬]
嵩山太室闕</kbd>

as the left part isn't as emphasised as this:

[image: 不]

---

This here

[image: 正]

cannot approximate the shape or follow the stroke order of

<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image: 正]
[正部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=66)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
隸
[image: 正]
[孫臏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Bin%27s_Art_of_War)37

[銀雀山漢簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinqueshan_Han_Slips)</kbd>

nearly as well as this:

[image]